# cannot find cforms action handler page

Tags: plugins, plugin-cforms

I'm not able to find the action handler page for the cforms plugin anywhere.

I want to write some function in the action handler page of the cforms plugin using the post values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main cforms plugin folder, find the file called `my-functions.php`. You can add functions to that file as needed. Its pretty well-commented.

What you want to do is add a function called `my_cforms_logic` or `my_cforms_action`, which get triggered at several different hooks during form submission and processing.

According to the docs, you can move the `my-functions.php` file (annd any css tweaks you make) into a separate folder called “cforms-custom” to protect your customizations from future upgrades...